# Is there a difference between a normal recursion and tail recursion in terms of space complexity?

Tags: scala, space-complexity

We have been working on tail recursion in Scala with our Professor and there was a mix of opinions if tail recursion had a space complexity of O(n) or O(1). What is the case? Is there a difference between languages/compilers?

Comment: The point of tail-recursion is to reuse the same stack frame... so, at least in terms of stack, it has a complexity of `O(1)`

Comment: There is a difference between languages, because not all compilers perform tail call optimization. For example, as far as I know, Java does not.